# JDK 7/JavaFX 2 application on Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: java, macos, javafx, javafx-2

I've just upgraded to El Capitan and I'm running into problems starting a custom JavaFX2 application running under JDK1.7.0u79 (the latest available from Oracle).

When starting the app, I'm getting this Exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.loadClass(Control.java:115)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.loadSkinClass(Control.java:1021)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.access$500(Control.java:70)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$12.invalidated(Control.java:972)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:127)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:161)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.set(StyleableStringProperty.java:71)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control$12.set(Control.java:964)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableStringProperty.applyStyle(StyleableStringProperty.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty.set(StyleableProperty.java:70)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper.transitionToState(StyleHelper.java:900)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_processCSS(Node.java:7418)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1146)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:1154)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.impl_processCSS(Parent.java:1153)
    at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:7386)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:454)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1468)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Scene.java:1535)
    at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Window.java:717)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:127)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:161)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:781)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:796)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:233)
    at au.com.religaresecurities.trademax.client.Start.start(Start.java:131)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.t2k.MacFontFinder.initPSFontNameToPathMap(MacFontFinder.java:339)
    at com.sun.t2k.MacFontFinder.getFontNamesOfFontFamily(MacFontFinder.java:390)
    at com.sun.t2k.T2KFontFactory.getFontResource(T2KFontFactory.java:233)
    at com.sun.t2k.LogicalFont.getSlot0Resource(LogicalFont.java:184)
    at com.sun.t2k.LogicalFont.getSlotResource(LogicalFont.java:228)
    at com.sun.t2k.CompositeStrike.getStrikeSlot(CompositeStrike.java:86)
    at com.sun.t2k.CompositeStrike.getMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:132)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontUtils.getFontMetrics(PrismFontUtils.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.font.PrismFontLoader.getFontMetrics(PrismFontLoader.java:466)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.<init>(Text.java:153)
    at javafx.scene.text.Text.<init>(Text.java:162)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ProgressIndicatorSkin.<clinit>(ProgressIndicatorSkin.java:78)
    ... 37 more
```

I can't just migrate the app to Java 8, so any help is much appreciated.

**Update**

I've been able to get the app running again by adding this to the start of my main method. Any better solutions out there?

```
    try {
        Class<?> macFontFinderClass = Class.forName("com.sun.t2k.MacFontFinder");
        Field psNameToPathMap = macFontFinderClass.getDeclaredField("psNameToPathMap");
        psNameToPathMap.setAccessible(true);
        psNameToPathMap.set(null, new HashMap<String, String>());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After more than a week with that in an extensive enterprise application, I haven't noticed any problems in the UI.

For the lack of a better solution, I'm accepting my update above as answer. Maybe it helps someone...

I've been able to get the app running again by adding this to the start of my main method.

```
    try {
        Class<?> macFontFinderClass = Class.forName("com.sun.t2k.MacFontFinder");
        Field psNameToPathMap = macFontFinderClass.getDeclaredField("psNameToPathMap");
        psNameToPathMap.setAccessible(true);
        psNameToPathMap.set(null, new HashMap<String, String>());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore
    }
```

Comment: still broke in 2016... smh

Comment: This solved the same issue for me, so thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer, however I thought it important to pass on that this bug has been identified and fixed in an upcoming Java release. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143907

Comment: Thanks, but disappointing that it takes such a long time to get an official resolution for this.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I changed the Text to a Label. I'm not sure it's possible in your case.

Comment: Nope, it's a quite complex application